# getValueIsAdjusting() disable in JList but now I cant select a choice twice in a row

Tags: java, jlist, listselectionlistener

I have a JList in which each option increments a variable and do some other simple stuff. My `ListSelectionListener` run twice at each selection with mouse, so I put the condition `if(!getValueIsAdjusting())` to run my code inside the listener just once per click selection. Now once I select, for example, option 1 it runs well, but if I want to select again this option nothing happens. So basically I cant select twice in a row the same option. (There is no problem if I go back to a choice I've chosen before). Any solution is welcomed. Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please add your relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to the problem and I wanted to share it with you guys.
After doing the stuff inside the **valueChanged** method I call the method
**clearSelection()**. This put the selected index to -1. To handle errors from this, in the the if condition I added **getSelectedIndex()>=0**. So the code:

```
private class KategoriHandler implements ListSelectionListener{    
public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {                if(!e.getValueIsAdjusting()&&kategori.getSelectedIndex()>=0){
//do the stuff;
kategori.clearSelection();}
```